# I want to programmatically generate a click on a DataGridView Row in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` in a form and I want to programmatically click its first row. I have found code to select its rows or columns from code.

For eg.

```
datagridview.Columns[0].Selected = true;
datagridview.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

However this code is not raising the `click event` on the datagridview. If any one has coded how to click a datagridview from code, please extend your kind help.

Comment: I am sure i am not understanding your question correctly...but i will stil ask - Why not just call your click eventhandler method directly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply call the event handler method e.g.:

```
datagridviewRowClickedEventHandler(new object(), new eventargs());
```

If you use the sender or e parameters in the event handler then you will need to work out how to pass in the correct values.

Answer (score 11):

Insert the follwing code into your project where appropriate (Usually on the form which has the datagridview).
Make sure to change the name of the DataGridView from **dataGridView1** to the appropriate one on your form.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call the cell click event with the first cell as the parameters.
    dataGridView1_CellClick(dataGridView1, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, 0));
}

private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //put your code for handling cell click here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the first half, setting the propers rows `Selected` value to true.  Now you can programatically call the row click handler and it should proceed as if you had clicked it within the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
datagridview.Columns[0].Selected = true;
datagridview.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

It makes look the row like selected but it won't change `dataGridView.CurrentRow`. So it could be an issue.

```
dataGridView.CurrentCell = dataGridView[<column>, <row>];
```

will change `CurrentRow` value too.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to apply `DataSource` and select the first row? Right?

The best way to do it like this

```
private async void DgvAreas_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

And here is the code to simulate click on row.

```
DgvAreas_RowStateChanged(dgvAreas, new DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs(dgvAreas.Rows[0],  DataGridViewElementStates.Selected));
```

In my case I have 3 `DataGridView`s so I populate the first one easly.
The second one I populate when user click the first DataGridView and in this case I use `DgvStaff_RowStateChanged` event.

And in this event `DgvStaff_RowStateChanged` I have the code to get data **async** and populate the third `DataGridView` and after I apply data source for the second `DataGridView` I need to get data for the first row of this view and display it in the third `DataGridView`. **It is cascade logic**.

```
private async void DgvStaff_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // For any other operation except, StateChanged, do nothing
                if (e.StateChanged != DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) return;

                if (sender is MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid)
                {
                    if ((sender as MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid).SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dgvGeoData.DataSource = null;
                        dgvAreas.DataSource = null;

                        metroProgressSpinnerMain.Visible = true;
                        panelFilter.Enabled = false;

                        dgvAreas.RowStateChanged -= DgvAreas_RowStateChanged;

                        var selectedRow = (sender as MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid).SelectedRows[0];
                        var machineModelShortView = (MachineModelShortView)selectedRow.DataBoundItem;

                        var startTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePickerStart.Value.ToShortDateString());
                        var endTime = Convert.ToDateTime(metroDateTimeEnd.Value.ToShortDateString());
                        var areas = await UpdateAreaItems(machineModelShortView.MachineID, startTime, endTime);

                        if (areas.Any())
                        {
                            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                            {
                                dgvAreas.DataSource = areas.OrderBy(x => x.AreaID).ThenBy(x => x.TimeStart).ToList();
                                dgvAreas.RowStateChanged += DgvAreas_RowStateChanged;

                                // !!! This is how you simulate click to the FIRST ROW dgvAreas.Rows[0]
                                DgvAreas_RowStateChanged(dgvAreas, 
                                    new DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs(dgvAreas.Rows[0],  DataGridViewElementStates.Selected));

                                metroProgressSpinnerMain.Visible = false;
                                panelFilter.Enabled = true;
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                            {
                                metroProgressSpinnerMain.Visible = false;
                                panelFilter.Enabled = true;
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```

And here

```
   private async void DgvAreas_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // For any other operation except, StateChanged, do nothing
                if (e.StateChanged != DataGridViewElementStates.Selected) return;

                //Get GeoData
                if (sender is MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid)
                {
                    if ((sender as MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid).SelectedRows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        dgvGeoData.DataSource = null;
                        metroProgressSpinnerMain.Visible = true;
                        panelFilter.Enabled = false;

                        var selectedRow = (sender as MetroFramework.Controls.MetroGrid).SelectedRows[0];
                        var areaItem = (AreaItem)selectedRow.DataBoundItem;
                        var geoData = await UpdateWDataPositionItems(areaItem.MachineID, areaItem.TimeStart, areaItem.TimeEnd.Value);

                        if (geoData.Any())
                        {
                            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                            {
                                dgvGeoData.DataSource = geoData.OrderBy(x => x.AtTime).ToList();
                                metroProgressSpinnerMain.Visible = false;
                                panelFilter.Enabled = true;
                            }));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                            {
                                metroProgressSpinnerMain.Visible = false;
                                panelFilter.Enabled = true;
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex);
            }
        }
```